# Stripe Payment Error: Must provide source or customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

I've been trying to implement a payment method for a shopping cart using card information attached to the user via a subscription model. And while the latter works fine, whenever I attempt to create a charge for the cart, I get the "Must provide source or error."

Here's some code to get started. Let me know if you need more.

checkouts_controller.rb

```
 def create

   customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
   source: params[:stripeToken],
   email: 'paying.user@example.com',
 )

   charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
   amount: current_cart.total,
   currency: 'usd',
   description: "Order ##{current_cart.id}"
 )

end
```

Error logs from Stripe Post Body

```
 {
   "amount": "9500",
   "currency": "usd",
   "description": "Order #1"
 }
```

And from the response body

```
 {
   "error": {
   "code": "parameter_missing",
   "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-    missing",
   "message": "Must provide source or customer.",
   "type": "invalid_request_error"
 }
```

}

I’m using the standard 4242 4242 4242 4242 card that is actually recorded and attached to my user via my subscription model. Card info like the brand, last four digits, expiration month and year all appear in my view when I go to add a different card. The stripe_id is also present when I check in the console.

I have checked stripe documentation and copied the snippet from their create action from https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails but this only trigged the error “Cannot charge a customer with no active card” despite the fact that this card is currently being used for a subscription.

So where did I goof at?

Comment: Hi @Grasshopper27, you are creating a Customer but not passing that along in your Charge request. You need to pass the customer.id as the `customer` parameter in your Charge creation request [0]. `source` is a required parameter on Charge creation, unless you pass in a Stripe Customer that has an attached source.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create#create_charge-customer

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but now I have a "Cannot charge customer that has no active card" error. This is strange because it's the same card being used for this user's subscription.

Comment: Hi @Grasshopper27, looks like the customer you created is not being created with the source. You should look into Dashboard -> Logs to look at the request body for the /customer creation request and see if the token is being passed in.

I would also like to note that this Rails doc is a bit outdated, you should try out updated Checkout to really simplify your integration: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout

Comment: Appreciate both pointers there, hmunoz. At least I have a better idea of what the problem is, which is more than I could say before. I'll do more digging, try a few things and then start fresh again in the morning. Thanks again.

Comment: @hmunoz, I was able to utilize checkout to fix the issue of the customer being created with the source. Since your suggestion pointed me in the right direction, I'd like to give you credit for it. If you'd care to post your comment as an answer, I can mark it as the correct one

Comment: super! Great to hear it solved your issue! Posted as an answer for you though both Mate's suggestion is correct too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> moving from comment to an answer

Hi @Grasshopper27, looks like the customer you created is not being created with the source. You should look into Dashboard -> Logs to look at the request body for the /customer creation request and see if the token is being passed in.

I would also like to note that this Rails doc is a bit outdated, you should try out updated Checkout to really simplify your integration: stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure that the `customer` you create is passed in on the charge create call:

```
   charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
     customer: customer,
     amount: current_cart.total,
     currency: 'usd',
     description: "Order ##{current_cart.id}"
   )
```

Or you can use the source directly as:

```
   charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
     source: params[:stripeToken],
     amount: current_cart.total,
     currency: 'usd',
     description: "Order ##{current_cart.id}"
   )
```

Both options and examples [can be found here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your answer would've probably worked but I think hmunoz might've been onto something when he suggested that the customer wasn't being created with the source. I'm currently redoing my signups between dealing with work and family issues and will post an update when I get things working in case others have a similar issue

Comment: Fair enough, though this answer is for the original question: The error related to the `charges` error. The other answer is about the second question / error you've had. Thanks for the update!